# Playing multiple vibrates on iPhone

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch

How can I play two or three vibrates in a row? Or different patterns of vibrate?

Repeating `AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(kSystemSoundID_Vibrate)` does not work. Only does a single vibrate.

Tried using callback

```
    OSStatus AudioServicesAddSystemSoundCompletion (
                                                SystemSoundID                           kSystemSoundID_Vibrate,
                                                CFRunLoopRef                            inRunLoop,
                                                CFStringRef                             inRunLoopMode,
                                                AudioServicesSystemSoundCompletionProc  vibrationDone,
                                                void                                    *inClientData
                                                );
```

but it does not trigger vibrationDone.

Answer (score 1):

Try registering a callback using `AudioServicesAddSystemSoundCompletion` to be notified when the vibrate "sound" has ended before attempting to play it another time. From the docs:

> Because a system sound may play for several seconds, you might want to know when it has finished playing. For example, you may want to wait until a system sound has finished playing before you play another sound.

NB: I haven't tried if this actually works.